# IF statements and returning to the start of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, return, statements

Im trying to input data from a form into an array,
everything is going fine but i've noticed even when submitting empty inputs it still records it into my array,
im trying to do a IF statement to check if the input field "Name" is empty then restart function and alert them its empty

right now its doing the opposite, alerting them its empty when its not visa versa,
I got it to work the other way around but ended up losing that save and forgot how i did it, I also couldnt figure out how to restart that function (to avoid it being added to the array)
heres my code,

```
function addRecord(){   
  employee.name = document.getElementById('name').value; 
  employee.age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  employee.position = document.getElementById('position').value;
  if(name.length == 0){
    alert('Do you not have a name, mate?');
    return false;
  }  
  employeeList.push(employee);
  employee = new Object();
  writeRecords();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `name` must be `employee.name` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if(!employee.name){
  alert('Do you not have a name, mate?');
  return
}
```

You can also use this logic for checking age and position.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Rahul, just one more thing, id like to reset the whole array when clicking a button,
would this work?


function resetButton(){
function resetButton(){

 employee.length = 0;

}




and then call that with 

document.getElementById('resetButton').addEventListener("click", function(event){
  
});

Comment: best solution is to assign the object keys like employee.name = "" or employee.age = "" or employee.position = "" or simply assign employee = {};

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are expecting to achieve.

```js
var employeeList = [];
function addRecord(){

var employee = {}
 employee.name = document.getElementById('name').value;


 employee.age = document.getElementById('age').value;


 employee.position = document.getElementById('position').value;


 if(!(employee.name && employee.age && employee.position)  ){

alert('The form is incomplete. Please revisit.');
return false;



}

 employeeList.push(employee);
 employee = new Object();
 resetForm();
console.log(employeeList)
}

function resetForm(){

 document.getElementById('name').value = '';
 document.getElementById('age').value = '';
 document.getElementById('position').value = '';
 }
```

```html
<input id='name'/>
<input id='age'/>
<input id='position'/>
<button onclick='addRecord()'>Add Employee</button>
```

Comment: Hi Ive found the write answer but i appreciate your help!